# how to test variable with chef not_if guard

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have following code not to be executed if software_version equals to 12
however not_if is not working, I am not sure syntax I am using is correct or not.

```
software_version = `command that pulls version`
bash 'extract_installer' do
cwd '/opt/tmp/'
code <<-EOH
tar -xvf #{cwd}/#{r_file}
....
...
EOH
not_if  "software_version".equal?(12)
end
```

Comment: I believe the "software_version" variable contains a string and you are comparing with integer. can you please do a small debug "puts" for that?

Answer (score 0):

`not_if { shell_out!('command that pulls version').stdout == '12' }`

Comment: While this snippet certainly appears to answer the question, please provide some additional context so that the rest of us can understand the answer, possibly reducing our own errors in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately when the question gives so little context, there is little to do but give the correct code and move on.